# How to assign Items to picker getting a list of data as a response in the form of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am facing a problem with adding the data to picker.item for which the data is in the form of a single array.

I have tried using the map and push for the array, but nothing seems to be working.

My array is as follows

```
[  "ABC",  "XYZ",  "123",  "aaa"]

   class XYZ extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {    statelist: ''        };
       list() {        
        fetch('myURL', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        },
        })
            .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                })
            .then((data) => {
                data.map((item,key)=>{
                    console.log(item,key,'item and key')
                    return(
                    <Item label={item} value={item} />)
                })
}
    async onStateChange(value) {
        await this.setState({
            statelist: value
        });}

    render() {
        return (
                <View >
                        <Picker
                            selectedValue={this.state.abc}
                            onValueChange={this.onStateChange.bind(this)}>
                            this.list()}
                        </Picker>
                </View>

        );
    };
}

export default withNavigation(XYZ);
```

I want a dropdown consisting of 5 options as shown above which should be all the 5 elements of the array.

Comment: What's the trouble that you're running into? `data.map((item)=> <Item label={item} value={item} />)` should work.

Comment: I am getting an empty dropdown even after using the above-mentioned code. The 'data' is the response I am getting from the services if this could help for a solution. @rb612

Comment: Can you show your entire file? You may be struggling with an asynchronous task.

Comment: I have edited the code. Hope it helps @Kobe

Comment: It may not be the cause of your problem, but you should add the `key` attribute to your Items. `<Item key={key} label={item} value={item} />`

Comment: And... where are you saving the result of your `map` function ? Can we see the full component ?

Comment: Nope @Treycos, It isn't working doing so.

Comment: Are you mutating the state once you receive the data ?

Comment: You should share the full component code

Comment: sure @Treycos, I would share enough useful code.

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the data from your call, and you are also handling an async call. You should get the data on each render, or once in `componentDidMount()`, and set the state.

```js
const DATA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

class Select extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {}
    }

    getList() {
        return Promise.resolve(DATA).then(data => data.map(item => <option label={item} value={item} />))
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getList().then(data => this.setState({ list: data }))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <select onChange={this.onStateChange}>
                {this.state.list || null}
            </select>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Select />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is having an error as this.getList.then is not a function. @Kobe

Comment: Did you bind the function first?

Comment: After Binding the function same error persists. @Kobe

Comment: Use `this.getList().then`

Answer (score 0):

In order to trigger an update on the component to add items, in your case you should use React state. In fact, using fetch you are doing an asynchronous operation that does not return immediately the result.

In your `then()`callback in the fetch, you save `data` into a state variable if you use hooks in function components ( look this link: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate ), or using `this.setState({data: data})` if you use class components.

Then in the return statement, you use the `data` variable (for function components):

```
return <Picker> 
    { data.map((item)=> <Item label={item} value={item} />) }
<Picker>
```

or in `render` method (for class components):

```
<Picker> 
    { this.state.data.map((item)=> <Item label={item} value={item} />) }
<Picker>
```

In any case, I can help you better if you share your file, otherwise I cannot write a complete example.

Comment: Thanks, marcodt89, and @Kobe I didn't get the solution yet. Can you please help me with an example. I think I should use 'for' loop for adding the items to the picker.

Answer (score 0):

here you can find a sample of what I meant using state of component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-select-from-array-190823-u1oux